# Not finding the h3 (title) class in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape the title, description and link of Google Results using selenium and store those in a dictionary. All is going well, except I cannot find a way to scrape the titles (h3). I think I'm just not using the right line to get this class. This is the error:

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"css selector","selector":".h3"}   (Session info:
> chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Here is my code. How to store the titles in the dictionary?

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

root = "https://www.google.com/"
url = "https://google.com/search?q="

query = 'Why do I only see the first 4 results?'  # Fill in google query
query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
link = url + query

print(f'Main link to search for: {link}')

options = Options()
# options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)

pageInfo = []
try:
   # wait for search results to be fetched
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "g"))
   )
 
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   
searchResults = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g')
for result in searchResults:
    element = result.find_element_by_css_selector('a')
    link = element.get_attribute('href')
    header = element.find_element_by_class_name('h3').text # Here I get an Error
    text = result.find_element_by_class_name('IsZvec').text
    pageInfo.append({
        'header' : header, 'link' : link, 'text': text
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem searching element inside element.
To search element with class_name `h3` inside the `element` you have to use the following code:

```
header = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,'h3')]')
```

this will search element with class name `h3` under `element`. Otherwise it will search on the entire page.
The same problem is actually with

```
element = result.find_element_by_css_selector('a')
```

it should be

```
element = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//a')
```

The same problem is with

```
text = result.find_element_by_class_name('IsZvec')
```

Comment: Great this helped A LOT! I indeed missed the right knowledge to search for nested classes, but now I do!

Comment: I'm really happy I could help you with this!

Comment: There's one final thing I'm still not getting, which is the title + description from Google Search results directed towards the Books.Google.com websites; I opened a new issue so perhaps you can help out again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672164/trouble-scraping-the-title-description-from-google-books-using-selenium

Comment: I see. I tried, but currently have no idea why is is occurs. It looks correct from the dev tools